# make the rest of the window grayed out

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup

Hope you can help me with this issue.
I am developing a Windows universal application (tablet app) in which I am using XAML Popups. When I display the popup using "popup.isOpen = true" and I have set the height and width for the popup. The problem is the rest of the controls on the window are also accessible.

I want grey out the actual window when I display the popup. When the popup is open, user should be able to use the controls on the popup but not the actual window.

Your suggestions/guidance will be very useful.

XAML

```
<Page
x:Name="PageName"
x:Class="TryingVariousThings.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TryingVariousThings"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="IsReadOnlyProperty Binding One" FontSize="29.333"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbkOne" Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=tbOne}" FontSize="29.333"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbOne"  IsReadOnly="{Binding ElementName=PageName, Path=setAsReadOnly, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Button Content="Disable editing" x:Name="bDisableEditing" Click="bDisableEditing_Click"></Button>
        <Button Content="Enable editing" x:Name="bEnableEditing" Click="bEnableEditing_Click"></Button>   
        <Button x:Name="bCustomPopup" Content="Show Custom Popup" Click="bCustomPopup_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <Popup x:Name="PopupOne"
           IsOpen="False"
           >
        <Grid
            Background="Aqua"
            Width="800"
            Height="400">
        <Button Width="200" Content="popupButton"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>

</Grid>
```

XAML.cs

```
  private void bCustomPopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PopupOne.Height = 400;
        PopupOne.Width = 800;
        PopupOne.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Comment: Popup is not like the Dialog at least in WinRT terms, also you can't style dialogs so I had to use some custom dialogs in order to achieve what the client wanted. We used a library called Callisto and it's `CustomDialog` but I had to do a lot of hacks to made the backgorund controls unavailable not only for touches but also for users with keyboard (keys like tab). Other than that you could try to put a Grid or other control on top of the whole screen and Show it to the user with some dark mask to achieve gray out effect, also consume all events. Another option would be to disable all controls.

Comment: Hi Kirotab, thanks for your suggestions. i tried "PageName.IsEnabled = false; " PageName is the  main Page in which i have all the stackpanels controls and popup. this disables the access the other controls. But also disables the controls on popup as the popup is within the page. After disabling the page i could not do 'PopupOne.isEnabled' this property was not there. any idea?

Comment: I also tried as I had few minutes now to check but it seems IsEnabled is missing on a lot of the controls in Universal ... Or at least it looks that way to me. I tried also with `container.IsHitTestVisible = false;` where container is the stack panel, but you could go around with tab and click the buttons at the back... Maybe if you also remove `IsTabStop` from the controls you could emulate the behavior but I can't find that property either ...

Comment: Hm I think that I've figured the workaround, you will bind your controls `IsTabStop` (those that the user can interact with) to the `IsOpened` property of your Popup, and with reverse boolean converter this will automatically disable tabulating over them also `IsHitTestVisible` of the container the same way bound to `IsOpened` of the popup. For the effect you could use the aforementioned workaround - mask over all with some opacity. Should I help you with example ?

Comment: yes please example will be so much useful as i am new to these things

Comment: I've added an answer and fixed small issue with it so check out the edit, hope it works for you.

Comment: hi kirtob, I tried the way Shaaman suggested and with you help, I posted the answer, I think that is much simpler. one issue i had was the popup controls are grayed out too. can you suggest any ways?

Comment: Sorry but you'r solution is not simpler, it's just incomplete in my opinion, as a user with keyboard connected to the tablet will be able to interact on the elements that are on the screen (even thought they are hidden and they can not be tapped/clicked). Also your solution is not resizing the popup when you change the screen or at least I assume that much (if you make the screen bigger than it was before opening the popup it will have not grayed out part.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

*NOTE: I'm basing my suggestions off Windows 8.1 WinRT application, NOT a Universal Application - if things end up being different I apologize in advance, I just hope this will put you on the right track.*

First, make your popup span the entire screen. Note, that I'm creating my popup in code-behind.

```
        Popup popup = new Popup()
        {
            Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height,
            IsLightDismissEnabled = false,
            Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width
        };

        popup.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 0);
        popup.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0);
```

Next, create a `<UserControl>` for the contents and in your XAML, make something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.4"/>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="Auto">
        <!-- Make sure the set the height and width based on % or something, so it looks good -->
        <RestOfYourXAML/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This way you "cover" the entire screen (visual effect of making it seem disabled).

Finally, specify the popup content and show it:

```
        MyUserControl popupContent = new MyUserControl();
        popup.Child = messageDialog;
        popup.IsOpen = true;
```

Note, that I want my popup to resemble system popups, so they span the entire width of the available screen and only the height changes. You can of course change that as you please by specifying the width and height of the `<Grid>` which holds the actual content in XAML.

Comment: Hi i have tried the way you have told me. I have made the Grid within the popup take the entire width and height and the horizontal and vertical aligned the controls. This is exactly what i wanted but the controls on the popup look grayed out too. is there any way I can keep the grid grayedout but not the controls?

Comment: @Rao I've noticed from your own answer... I didn't give you enough information. The XAML isn't for a `<Popup>`, but rather for a `<UserControl>` which is later used as the content of a `Popup`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Rao Also, note that the "black grid" doesn't have any content, really. It's just there to provide the "disabled" effect on other controls. And finally, it needs to be BEFORE other content in the XAML or otherwise it'll make everything darker, as you described.

Answer (score 0):

OK here's the example for the workaround that we discussed in the comments of your answer. If there is a better way will be glad to know.

What we do is:

- Bind our container `IsHitTestVisible` property to `IsOpen` property of the popup
- Bind our interact-able controls property `IsTabStop` to `IsOpen` of the popup
- Use reverse bool converter to get the wanted values (opposite of `IsOpen`)
- Stretch the size of the Popup's first element which is a border that we use to apply darkened mask on (dark color with opacity) to the curent window's size (done in the code behind)
- When you click the button in the popup it closes the popup and all is visible and interact-able again

**XAML**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:BoolToOppositeConverter x:Name="OppositeBoolConverter" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayMaskColorBrush" Color="#88000000" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="container">
    <StackPanel 
        IsHitTestVisible="{Binding Path=IsOpen, ElementName=PopupOne, Converter={StaticResource OppositeBoolConverter}}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkZero" Text="IsReadOnlyProperty Binding One" FontSize="29.333"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbkOne" Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=tbOne}" FontSize="29.333"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbOne"  IsReadOnly="{Binding ElementName=PageName, Path=setAsReadOnly, Mode=OneWay}" 
                 IsTabStop="{Binding Path=IsOpen, ElementName=PopupOne,Converter={StaticResource OppositeBoolConverter}}"/>
        <Button Content="Disable editing" x:Name="bDisableEditing" Click="bDisableEditing_Click"
                IsTabStop="{Binding Path=IsOpen, ElementName=PopupOne, Converter={StaticResource OppositeBoolConverter}}"/>
        <Button Content="Enable editing" x:Name="bEnableEditing" Click="bEnableEditing_Click"
                IsTabStop="{Binding Path=IsOpen, ElementName=PopupOne, Converter={StaticResource OppositeBoolConverter}}"/>
        <Button x:Name="bCustomPopup" Content="Show Custom Popup" Click="bCustomPopup_Click"
                IsTabStop="{Binding Path=IsOpen, ElementName=PopupOne, Converter={StaticResource OppositeBoolConverter}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Popup x:Name="PopupOne"
           IsOpen="False"
           IsLightDismissEnabled="False">
        <Border x:Name="popupMask" Background="{StaticResource GrayMaskColorBrush}">
            <Grid Background="White" Width="800" Height="400">
                <Button Width="200" Content="popupButton" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

**Main Page - code behind**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

private void bCustomPopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popupMask.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    popupMask.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;

    Window.Current.SizeChanged += Current_SizeChanged;

    PopupOne.IsOpen = true;
}

private void Current_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    popupMask.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    popupMask.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PopupOne.IsOpen = false;
    Window.Current.SizeChanged -= Current_SizeChanged;
}
```

**Converter for opposite bool**

```
class BoolToOppositeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

**EDIT a fix for when window is resizing and usage of the new binding {x:bind}**

There was an issue when you resize the window the popup stayed the same size it was initially so I've added a fix in the code behind, registering to size changed event and taking the window's size again (you could do that part in opened and closed events of the popup if you prefer instead of the clicks

Also as we are building Universal app you could use the new syntax for binding (they said it is faster than the old one, but it's defaulting to `OneTime` instead of `OneWay` so we have to set the mode manually)

```
"{x:Bind PopupOne.IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource OppositeBoolConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
```

you could use this instead of the previous binding example

Comment: Hi Kirotab I tried the way Shaaman has suggested which was a little bit simple may be this will help as well. but I did have an issue though the popup seems grayed out too. Let me post the XAMl and XAML.cs seperately.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Shaaman and with the help of kirotab, here is my XAML and Xaml.cs to gray out the background of a Popup.
The popup is set to the window width and height and then the stack panel of the controls centered.
but only thing is the controls on the popup looks grayed out too. Any way I can anti gray the popup controls?

EDIT: Changed the OPACITY to 0.9 and that fixed it. 
THANKS TO SHAAMAN AND KIROTAB FOR HELPING ME OUT

XAML

```
<Page
x:Name="PageName"
x:Class="TryingVariousThings.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TryingVariousThings"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">


<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel x:Name="spControls">

        <Button x:Name="bCustomPopup" Content="Show Custom Popup" Click="bCustomPopup_Click"></Button>


    </StackPanel>

        <Popup x:Name="PopupOne"
           IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=PageName, Path=setPopup, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Grid
            x:Name="gridPopupOne"
            Background="Black"
            Opacity="0.9">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                 <Button Content="Cancel Popup" x:Name="bCancelPopup" Click="bCancelPopup_Click"></Button>
                <TextBox Text="abcd"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
    </Popup>

</Grid>
```

XAML.cs

```
private void bCustomPopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        gridPopupOne.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
        gridPopupOne.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
        setPopup = true;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPopup = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "setPopup",
      typeof(bool),
      typeof(MainPage),
      new PropertyMetadata(false)
      );

    public bool setPopup
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPopup); }
        set { SetValue(IsPopup, value); }

    }

    private void bCancelPopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        setPopup = false;
    }
```

Comment: This... isn't what I suggested, but I'm happy that it worked out for you. Also, if other answers helped you, why not +1 those answers?